# Error getting shortened URL using tinyurl API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a URL shortener using TinyUrl. The problem is that I get the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: 'Error on the remote server: (400) Incorrect request.
```

I have already tried reading in almost the entire site but I have not found the solution.

The controller code is:

```
namespace Prueba.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class TinyURLAPIController : Controller
    {
        // GET: TinyURLAPI
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MakeTinyUrl(string strURL)
        {
            var tinyUrl = WebRequest.Create("http: / tinyurl . com/api-create.php?url=" + strURL);
            var shortUrl = tinyUrl.GetResponse();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(shortUrl.GetResponseStream())){
                ViewData["tinyUrl"] = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return PartialView("Index");

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the index code:

```
<Html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <@Ajax.BeginForm("MakeTinyUrl", new AjaxOptions  { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "tinyUrl" }))>
        @Html.TextBox("url")
        <input id="btnMakeUrl" type="submit" value="Make tinyUrl" onclick="Index" />



</body>
</Html>
```

I need to enter the long URL in a textbox and pressing the button shows the short URL in a label

Comment: `WebRequest.Create("la api de tiny=" + strURL);` does not seem correct at all. You should be making a valid web request in the form of `https://example.com`. You should be able to set a breakpoint on your `ActionResult` and see what is going wrong specifically. I am confident that the issue is the URL you enter is not valid.

Comment: Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create?view=netframework-4.8 for valid examples. As I suspected your URI is almost certainly invalid due to `la api de tiny=` concatenated to the beginning. Remove that text.

Comment: 'la api de tiny' is a really api implemented in my code but i can't introduce links in the question

Comment: Understood. Then you will need to debug. Look at the value of your API + `strURL` and ensure it is a valid URI.

Comment: Yeah, is a valid uri 'cause if i write api+http://example.com in a nav bar the page shows the shortened url

Comment: You read the response twice. Do both reads fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't comment so i'll just write it as an answer!

Your problem isn't the api request.
Your strURL is probably null as it was for me with your code.
Try making the following change in your view:

```
from
@Html.TextBox("url") 

to
@Html.TextBox("strURL")
```

and also your html isn't quite valid where you defined the form.
try:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MakeTinyUrl", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "tinyUrl" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("strURL")
    <input id="btnMakeUrl" type="submit" value="Make tinyUrl" onclick="Index" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Really, thank you! this is the answer that i need, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It' possible you may have to UrlEncode the value before passing it to the view:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

I understand you've altered the api link in your post due to restrictions.

firstly i'd manually call the api in your preferred browser using the URL you're trying to shorten...make sure that is ok.

e.g. `[redacted]tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://www.yoururltest.com`

Next, run a test with a breakpoint, stepping through your code to see exactly where the error happens and view the data your controller receives and uses in the request.

I bet you'll find an issue with that somewhere along the way